# Script for searching for the desired modal window (by the Id button) (Does not work)

Tags: jquery, html

Take the Id button and use the switch to "search" the case with the same id and change the `display: none` style to `block`.

More clearly described in the code as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(this).click(function () { //When I click on some link, take its id (this), for example it's myBtm
            switch ($(this).id) { //replaces if
                case "myBtn": //If this === myBtn
                    $("#myModal").show("display", "block");//This function is performed here, otherwise it looks further
                    break;
            }
        })
    })
});
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 7;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .modal-content h1 {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 70px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

    .modal-content p {
        width: 600px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

.modal_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-content span {
    font-size: 23px;
}

.modal-content img {
    height: 20vw;
    z-index: 7;
}

.close {
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 40px;
}

.modal-2 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content-2 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 7;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .modal-content-2 h1 {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 70px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

.modal-content p {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.modal_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-content span {
    font-size: 23px;
}

.modal-content img {
    height: 20vw;
    z-index: 7;
}

.close {
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="myBtn">УЗНАТЬ ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
<div>
    <a href="#" id="myBtn-2">УЗНАТЬ ПОДРОБНЕ2Е</a>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal_container">
            <span class="close">&#10006;</span>
            <h1>123</h1>
            <p>123</p>
            <div class="picture">
                <img src="img/orel-3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal-2" class="modal-2">
        <div class="modal-content-2">
            <div class="modal_container-2">
                <span class="close">&#10006;</span>
                <h1>123</h1>
                <p>123</p>
                <div class="picture">
                    <img src="img/orel-3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When pressed, it should select a modal window from one of several buttons.

https://codepen.io/oleggood22/pen/rZLMaY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

> **Problem 1** : There is minor mistake to get `ID` you need to use jQuery
>   attribute `attr()` in order to get `ID`
>
> **Problem 2** : Your second model `id="myModal-2"` is inside your first
>   model `id="myModal"`, you need to move it out so it will be visible by
>   clicking on second link.
>
> **Problem 3** : jQuery `show()` function is itself to make any element visible, you don't need to write `"display", "block"` inside.

Here i fixed the problems, pleae check it:

```js
$('a').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    switch ($(this).attr('id')) { //replaces if
        case "myBtn": //If this === myBtn
            $("#myModal").show();//This function is performed here, otherwise it looks further
            break;
        case "myBtn-2": //If this === myBtn-2
            $("#myModal-2").show();//This function is performed here, otherwise it looks further
            break;
    }

});
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 7;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .modal-content h1 {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 70px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

    .modal-content p {
        width: 600px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

.modal_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-content span {
    font-size: 23px;
}

.modal-content img {
    height: 20vw;
    z-index: 7;
}

.close {
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 40px;
}

.modal-2 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content-2 {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 7;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .modal-content-2 h1 {
        color: #1C1C1C;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 70px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

.modal-content p {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.modal_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-content span {
    font-size: 23px;
}

.modal-content img {
    height: 20vw;
    z-index: 7;
}

.close {
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="myBtn">УЗНАТЬ ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
<div>
    <a href="#" id="myBtn-2">УЗНАТЬ ПОДРОБНЕ2Е</a>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal_container">
            <span class="close">&#10006;</span>
            <h1>123</h1>
            <p>123</p>
            <div class="picture">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div id="myModal-2" class="modal-2">
        <div class="modal-content-2">
            <div class="modal_container-2">
                <span class="close">&#10006;</span>
                <h1>123</h1>
                <p>123</p>
                <div class="picture">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Note** : Above code is working but your still need to work on css for presentation and other jquery related to closing the model and

But i hope that your will understand the concepts, thanks.

Comment: Yes, many thanks (also helped with `display: none`, did not understand why the window does not disappear, the problem was in `show`, but it needed `css`.

Comment: As i said, `.close` event is now written yet,  you have to write it down.